# Tensorflow module not found with tensorflow 2, where to find docs for new way?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, upgrade, tensorflow2.0

[following this tutorial](https://medium.com/deep-writing/how-to-write-with-artificial-intelligence-45747ed073c)
I am trying to run a pre-written model for TensorFlow, and because I am running TensorFlow 2, and the code I am using was meant for an older version. specifically, tf.contrib.

From original code:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import legacy_seq2seq
```

From first fix I found:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops.seq2seq import sequence_loss
```

error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.ops.seq2seq'

Where do I find the methods that were in tf.contrib, and import them and use them? Do the old functionalities still exist?

Comment: `tf.contrib` has been deprecated for a long time and has been removed from TF2. Functionality has been either removed altogether, or moved to other parts of TF. The `tf.python.ops` module, IIRC, has been made private. Change tutorial and search for one based on `keras` or specifically TF2.

Comment: @GPhilo Thanks! Do you think i could re write the model.py page using keras? or should i scrap everything and find another demo like you said?

Comment: IMO you have a better chance of finding a better tutorial specific for Keras/TF2. I did not look at this one, but if they use lefacy_seq2seq I'd not consider it very up-to-date anyway

Comment: Good to know! Thanks for this input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please note that **tf.contrib has been dropped in TF 2.0**. [Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/roadmap#tensorflow_20_beta_is_available)

> - Removal of [tf.contrib](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib) - These features have been either moved to TensorFlow Core, or to tensorflow/addons, or are no longer part of the TensorFlow build but are developed and maintained by their respective owners.
> - Updated and revised documentation, examples, and website, including migration docs and TF 1.x to 2.0 converter guide.

For example `tf.contrib.layers.layer_norm`, according to [this github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/26854#issuecomment-474240037) got moved to here: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/layers.

## TF 2.0: `seq2seq` is under `tensorflow_addons` now

You can find a github post on how to handle `seq2seq` for TF 2.0 under tensorflow_addons: https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq. It gives you a clear example on how convert TF 1.x `seq2seq` into its TF 2.0
equivalent. Look under [***Sample code and Migration guide from TF 1.X***](https://github.com/tensorflow/addons/tree/master/tensorflow_addons/seq2seq#sample-code-and-migration-guide-from-tf-1x)

```py
# TF 2.0
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
sampler = tfa.seq2seq.sampler.TrainingSampler()
```

## TF **`1.x`** to TF **`2.0`** Upgrade

I would suggest you to first try and migrate the TF 1.x code to TF 2.0. Refer to [how to automatically upgrade from TF 1.x to TF 2.0?](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade)

#### [Recommended upgrade process](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/upgrade#recommended_upgrade_process)

[image]